# Spark dataframe to sparse vector with null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am facing a problem when I try to assemble a vector form a dataframe (Some columns contain `null` values) in scala. Unfortunately `vectorAssembler` cannot handle `null` values.

What I can do is to replace or fill dataframe's `null` values and then create a `dense` vector but that is not what I want.

So I thought about converting my dataframe rows to a `sparse` vector.  But how can I achive this? I have not found an option for the `vectorAssembler` to make a sparse vector.

EDIT: Actually I do not need `null` in the sparse vector but it shouldn't be a value like `0` or any other as it would be the case for a dense vector.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it manually like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkException
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder

case class Row(a: Double, b: Option[Double], c: Double, d: Vector, e: Double)

val dataset = spark.createDataFrame(
  Seq(new Row(0, None, 3.0, Vectors.dense(4.0, 5.0, 0.5), 7.0),
    new Row(1, Some(2.0), 3.0, Vectors.dense(4.0, 5.0, 0.5), 7.0))
).toDF("id", "hour", "mobile", "userFeatures", "clicked")

val sparseVectorRDD = dataset.rdd.map { row =>
  val indices = ArrayBuilder.make[Int]
  val values = ArrayBuilder.make[Double]
  var cur = 0
  row.toSeq.foreach {
    case v: Double =>
      indices += cur
      values += v
      cur += 1
    case vec: Vector =>
      vec.foreachActive { case (i, v) =>
        indices += cur + i
        values += v
      }
      cur += vec.size
    case null =>
      cur += 1
    case o =>
      throw new SparkException(s"$o of type ${o.getClass.getName} is not supported.")
  }
  Vectors.sparse(cur, indices.result(), values.result())
}
```

And then convert it back to a dataframe if needed. Since Row objects are not type checked, you have to handle it manually and cast to the appropriate type if needed.